# What is the error "expected expression before char" in my C program?

Tags: c

I don't really know what is wrong with my program. Any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define k_num_of_keywords 35
#define k_length_of_string 10


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

FILE *fp; //holds file pointer
int c; //holds the character as it reads
char *keywords[k_num_of_keywords]; //array of character pointers
int key_counter = 0;

fp = fopen("./keywords", "r");
if(NULL == fp){
    printf("Failed to create file!!\n");
    exit(0);//if file isn't opened exit program because need the file open
}

while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
//starts reading a char at a time until 1 string is created to compare
//and then it is added to the character pointer array
char temp[k_length_of_string];
short count = 0;

    if(c == '\n') {
        temp[count] = '\0';
        int len = strlen(temp);
        keywords[key_counter] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len +1));
        memcpy(keywords[key_counter], temp, len +1);
        key_counter++;
        //now empty temp to reuse it again incase there are more strings left
        int z;
        for(z = 0; z < count; z++)
            temp[z] = '\0';

    } else  {
        temp[count] = c;
        count++;
    }

}//end of while loop
int s;
for(s = 0; s < k_num_of_keywords; s++)
printf("keyword: %s\n", keywords[s]);


}//end of main function
```

The error I am getting is
"hw1.c: In function ‘main’:
hw1.c:49: error: expected expression before ‘char’"

EDIT: I apologize for how I named the variables at first before this edit. I did not realize I left that. I put that to fix an error I had thinking it wouldn't work. But now I have another issue. The output of the program after I fix the typo is:

```
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
keyword: 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: ...and while mildly humorous in an immature toilet sort of way, your naming of temp variables leaves some to be desired :).

Comment: I am sure its obvious but its also suppose to be printing out strings after "keyword:"

Comment: @Andy: I've edited my answer with some extra hints. There are a few other problems with the code (eg you probably don't need to empty the temp array, it will be written over each time anyway). It's probably better to try a few more things between questions so that people don't feel like you're asking them to code for you. Similarly, please open another question if your original question is answered.

Comment: @TimothyJones I do apologize about that. I will certainly keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing immediately stands out:

```
size0f(char)
```

Should be

```
sizeof(char)
```

(note the `o`  instead of `0`)

---

Now that you've fixed that, I'd say you're having problems because `temp` and `count` are declared inside your while loop, but they should really be declared before the loop. Don't forget to reset `count` when you finish reading a string. Also,

```
for(s = 0; s < k_num_of_keywords; s++)
```

should probably be:

```
for(s = 0; s < key_counter; s++)
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler complained about a particular line number--look harder at that line to find any typos, unintended symbols, etc. It's probably even clearer in the font used in the post

Answer (score 1):

```
keywords[key_counter] = (char *)malloc(size0f(char) * (len +1));
```

It is [`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) and not `size0f`.